# MySQL Table Alias Name Only Resulting First Alias in Union

Tags: mysql

I have multiple tables `amazonlistings` `ebaylistings` `shopifylistings` with the same column `SKU`.

I'm trying to create a query that searches the `SKU` column in all these tables. Right now I'm doing this with UNION.

```
$channeldetectquery = "(SELECT SKU as amazon FROM amazonlistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]') 
    UNION
(SELECT SKU as ebay FROM ebaylistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]')
    UNION
(SELECT SKU as shopify FROM shopifylistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]');"
```

If I do these individually...

```
SELECT SKU as ebay FROM ebaylistings WHERE SKU = 'Product SKU'
```

it provides the SKUS from ebay as intended... but for some reason when trying to use the above query with `UNION` it is only providing the first alias (`amazon`) no matter the result.

My intended result (now, I'm not sure if this is ideal or not, but this is what I was trying to achieve), would be like

```
[amazon]  [ebay]  [shopify]
 SKU 1              SKU 1

[amazon]  [ebay]  [shopify]
           SKU 2
```

etc... an empty result set (or no result set), if the SKU is not found, and a result if the SKU is found.  This allows me to check and see if the SKU is found in the appropriate table.

Comment: This is the expected behavior because a SQL result is only 2 dimensional. How do you want your result set to look? Please post a sample desired result. A common solution is to add a string literal like `SELECT SKU, 'amazon' AS source FROM amazonlistings` where the `source` output column will contain the variable source table value.

Comment: Also, you wrote `$channelskuarray[$i]`, so you repeat this in loop?

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the tidbit.  I updated my question. @Oleksandr Savchenko that is correct..

Comment: @bbruman if you are going to find throw array of values I suggest to do it like `where sku in ($channelskustring)` where `$channelskustring = implode(',', $channelskuarray)`. Something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The select union build a  resulting table  and a table can have only a column name so you can't assign different alias  to the same column  name  .. and for this reason sql return only the first

You can't obtain different alias from the union this way

instead you could mark each value with  a proper  value

```
 $channeldetectquery = 
"(SELECT  'amazon' as source, SKU FROM amazonlistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]') 
    UNION
(SELECT 'ebay', SKU  FROM ebaylistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]')
    UNION
(SELECT 'shopify', SKU  FROM shopifylistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]');"
```

In this way you obatain different qualfied  rows

and the you could

```
select * from 
(SELECT  'amazon' as source, SKU FROM amazonlistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]') 
    UNION
(SELECT 'ebay', SKU  FROM ebaylistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]')
    UNION
(SELECT 'shopify', SKU  FROM shopifylistings WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]') t
where t.SKU  =  'YOUR_SKU'
```

obtaining all the YOUR_SKU product for all the source

But if you need all the result for same SKU on the same row  (like in the sample you provided ) you should use  left join

```
$channeldetectquery = 
"(SELECT amazonlistings.SKU as amazon, ebaylistings.SKU as ebay, hopifylistings.SKU as shopify  FROM amazonlistings 
LEFT JOIN ebaylistings  ON amazon.SKU = ebaylistings.SKU
LEFT JOIN hopifylistings ON amazon.SKU = hopifylistings.SKU
WHERE amazon.SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]'
WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]') ";
```

Comment: Working it out, looking good. Source column was ideal.  Thanks!